# Why is the click event triggered on the child instead of listening DOM element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<div ng-click="handleClick($event)">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

with the JS:

```
$scope.handleClick = function($event) {
  $scope.target = $event.target.tagName;
  $event.stopPropagation();
};
```

I don't understand why the `$event.target` received is the `<input />` tag instead of the `<div>` that wraps it.

Here's a plunkr of the situation: http://plnkr.co/edit/9dIMPDUsUWJd3r9lWmZD?p=preview

**EDIT**: Apparently, the same goes with jQuery: https://plnkr.co/edit/qxvt7Gh9o61W4exBOB7V?p=preview

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  $('#wrapper').on('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target.tagName;
    $('p').text('The target element is '+target);
  });    
});

<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `target` property gets the element on which the event originally
>   occurred

In your case - `input`, since that's what you actually clicked on.

> The `currentTarget` property refers to the element whose event
>   listener triggered the event

In your case - the `div`, since that's where you placed the `listener`.

Simply change `$event.target.tagName;` to `$event.currentTarget.tagName;`.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lafnuOdjM0EwpIUGV5BQ?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Because you click on input? Height of div is not defined, so it is the same as input height.

But  div (again by default) takes all width. If you click in top-right corner - you will click on div.